# Imagick fails to read pdf files or takes extremely too long time to read it

Tags: php, imagick

I want to get a PDF thumbnail by converting the first page of the pdf file to an image using PHP, so I tried this code:

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick(realpath('my.pdf')."[0]");
$image->setResolution( 300, 300 );
$image->setImageFormat( "png" );
$image->writeImage('my.png');
?>
```

when I run the above code in Xampp, the page would load for a long time then I get this error
[The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdxVu.png)

I thought that the pdf file is too large, so I used a smaller pdf (13KB) and it didn't work.

then I started to check which line causes this lag, so I omitted all lines and left this one only:

```
$image = new Imagick(realpath('my.pdf')."[0]");
```

then I found out that this line is causing the trouble, so I thought that the problem might be because Imagick is not properly installed, but I checked and it seems okay.

I tried to open an image instead:

```
$image = new Imagick(realpath('my.jpg'));
```

and it worked perfectly.

so, where is the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: how big is that page of the PDF? It sounds like it might be just too big for your system to deal with.

Comment: I used a very small one (13KB) which is one page only.